# Typing square root symbol in textarea

Tags: html, javascript

How to type square root symbol in textarea in html ? I don't want character mapping method in XP. May be by typing ASCII code or something can I get that symbol ?

Comment: Here, you can copy it: √

Answer (score 4):

The "in html" part of the question suggests to me this was migrated away from SO incorrectly. By "typing", did you mean in your HTML source? If so, what you're looking for is [character entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references), in this case `&radic;`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to achieve a square root symbol by typing any of the following into your HTML: "`&radic;`", "`&#8730;`", or "`&#x221A;`" (quote marks for clarity, they aren't part of the entity you enter).  For a table with this and other symbols see: http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/symbols.html.

Comment: Your entity reference is better than the wikipedia one.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, type `Alt+251`.

In Mac OSX, type `Option+V`.

Comment: Alt+251 yields ¹ here ...

Comment: It yields √ here which looks to me like what I was looking for. Thanks